# Pandas checking each value in dataframe and replace it if condition is fullfilled

Tags: pandas, for-loop, replace, warnings

I want to replace all for values (227 rows, 397 columns)   in a dataframe less than a certain value (b) with zero and the rest should be the existing value - b . Its a kind of a Baseline correction.
I have a solution which works: loop over every value check the condition and replace it.

```
import pandas as pd
b = 20
    
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for col in df.columns:
        if df.loc[index, col] <= b:
            df.loc[index, col] = 0.0
        else:
            df.loc[index, col] = df.loc[index, col] - b
```

The code works but i get this warning from pandas:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) here with `DataFrame` constructor for avoid looping and [improve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24870953/does-pandas-iterrows-have-performance-issues/24871316#24871316):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df <= b, 0, df - b), index=df.index, columns= df.columns)
```

Or subtract values and set `0` by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.sub(b).mask(df <= b, 0)
```